# How to detect SUB character and remove it from a text file in C#?

Tags: c#, string, text

I am writing a program to process special text files. Some of these text files end with a SUB character (a substitute character. It may be 0x1A.)  How do I detect this character and remove it from the text file using C#?

Comment: When you say it *may* be 0x1A - is it *actually* U+001A when you read it, or not?

Comment: I can not see what it is. When I open this file in Notepad++, it shows as SUB. I researched online for the special SUB character, it points to me that the SUB is a special UNIX like character and it is 26 in ASCII and it is 0X1A in hex and it is Ctrl+Z. But how do I detect ctrl+z then?

Comment: "Ctrl+Z" isn't a character, it's presses on a keyboard. You should open the file in a *binary* file editor, to check that it's really byte 1A.

Comment: you are talking about newline character???? char 10?? just Ctrl+H, go into extended mode and write \n and replace it everywhere....

Comment: Removing the 0x1A from some "cleverly" constructed files may make the files unreadable. Long ago, in a galaxy far, far away, 0x1A was used to indicate end-of-file (EOF) in text streams. Later, some folks put a text header on their binary file, separating text from binary with a 0x1A char. A text reader would read and display characters from the file until it encountered the 0x1A. Net result: you could use MSDOS "type" command to display a binary file and see the text header/description without having to wade through a ton of bleeps and garbage chars racing across the screen.

Comment: There was an quick answer given by someone and then it was deleted. I tried it and it worked. So I want just to thank him for helping. The answer is like : var ftxt = String.Join("", ftxt.Where(x => x != '\x1a'));

Comment: @user981848: That was deleted as it's not a particularly readable or efficient way of doing it, basically. It would certainly work, but it's not the best way of doing it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If it's really 0x1A in the binary data, and if you're reading it as an ASCII or UTF-8 file, it should end up as U+001A when read in .NET. So you *may* be able to write something like:

```
string text = File.ReadAllText("file.txt");
text = text.Replace("\u001a", "");
File.WriteAllText("file.txt", text);
```

Note that the `"\u001a"` part is a string consisting of a single character: `\uxxxx` is an escape sequence for a single UTF-16 code point with the given Unicode value expressed in hex.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think that this will work and I will try it.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest answer would probably be a Regex:

```
public static string RemoveAll(this string input, char toRemove)
{
   //produces a pattern like "\x1a+" which will match any occurrence
   //of one or more of the character with that hex value
   var pattern = @"\x" + ((int)toRemove).ToString("x") + "+";

   return Regex.Replace(input, pattern, String.Empty);
}

//usage
var cleanString = dirtyString.RemoveAll((char)0x1a);
```

Yes, you could just pass in the int, but that requires knowing the integer value of the character. using a char as a parameter allows you to specify a literal or char variable with less muck.

Comment: I fail to see why a regular expression is required here. It's not like we're looking for a *pattern* here - you can just replace a string with the empty string. If you want to make it variable, you can use `ToString` easily.

Comment: If there are multiple adjacent occurrences, wouldn't the Regex remove them all in one go instead of going through the string one char at a time?

Comment: Well it's got to go through the string one char at a time - what makes you think that the Regex.Replace method is more efficient than String.Replace? It's not like I'm suggesting a separate String.Replace call for each occurrence...

Comment: Regex for one char might add a bit of overhead in this case

Answer (score 1):

C# has a method to detect control characters (including SUB).
See msdn : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9s05w2k9(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could also try something like this it should work

```
using (FileStream f = File.OpenRead("path\\file")) //Your filename + extension  
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(f)) 
    {
        string text = sr.ReadToEnd();
        text = text.Replace("\u001a", string.Empty);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't believe there's a `string.Replace(char, string)` method. Note that using `File.ReadAllText` makes the code simpler.

Comment: John I will double check this to make sure and let you know hold one sec.. and yes File.ReadAllText is simpler I was just offering a different suggestion..

Comment: @JonSkeet I changed the code.. thanks for the catch on that.. +1 to you